# What format to enter an NSDate in

Tags: ios, nsdate, icalendar

This is how I am adding an event to Ical I just dont know how to make the start date something other than the current day, as well as set the duration as an all day event.

```
> EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
>         [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
>             if (!granted) { return; }
>             EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
>             event.title = @"Hits THermal DC I";
>             event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
>             event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
>             [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
>             NSError *err = nil;
>             [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
>             NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
>         }];
```

Comment: Well, presumably you'd use some sort of UI element to enter the starting date/time, and the duration.  What UI elements did you have in mind?

Comment: The event that is being added is a fixed date. the user does not change it. I just need to know what format to enter the NSDate in

Comment: If you've already got the date what do you have to enter?  If you mean you have a date/time string, then you need to define an NSDateFormatter to translate that to an NSDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create any date with your own values, do this:

```
NSCalendar* calendar=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];    

NSDateComponents* dateComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComps setYear:1990];
[dateComps setMonth:11];
[dateComps setDay:10];

NSDate* starDate=[calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = @"Hits THermal DC I";
    event.startDate = starDate
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
    [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
    NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
}];
```

Comment: Yes but how do I set the start date to a specific date in time

Comment: `[dateComps setYear: year];
          [dateComps setMonth: month_or_week];
          [dateComps setDay: day];
          [dateComps setHour: hour];
          [dateComps setMinute: minute];
          [dateComps setSecond: second];
          date = [calendar dateFromComponents: dateComps];`

Comment: where in the cod e do I impliment that?

Comment: Before you initialization, create a `NSDateComponents` and put the values for your date, create your date, then, create EKEventStore object and pass the parameter of startDate.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but could you possibly show me that code im not that advanced. thank you for your time so far

Comment: in the line that starts with NSDate fifth line I believe you say calendario? I get an error "use of undeclared identifier 'calendario'" any suggestions?